# Arrrow functions in JavaScript ES6 - with and without curly braces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, ecmascript-2017

Like to ask about the differences in ES6 in function syntax - with and without curly braces.

both functions are working:

1. function with a curly braces:

   ```
   const function = () => {some code;};
   ```
2. same function without curly braces:

   ```
   const function = () => some code;
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is always useful.

Comment: A single statement does not need curly braces.  More than that does.  See "concise body vs. usual block body" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

Indeed these functions without curly braces are a shorthand version that differs in some nuances.

the most important differences are:

- they can have only one statement. (e.g. `() => 20 * 5`)
- they automatically return the value of that statement (above example would return the value 100)

Sticking to the example above, the more classic version to write this would be `() => {return 20 * 5}`

more details [can be found here for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).